# Problem when generating JUnit report on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, junit

I'm creating a post job on Jenkins pipeline to publish test results using junit, html and cobertura. The code looks like this

```
            post {
                always {
                    publishTestResults(
                        script: this,
                        junit: [
                            active:true,
                            allowEmptyResults:true,
                            archive: true,
                            pattern: '**/reports/mocha.xml',
                            updateResults: true
                        ],
                        cobertura: [
                            active:true,
                            allowEmptyResults:true,
                            archive:true,
                            pattern: '**/coverage/cobertura/cobertura-coverage.xml'
                        ],
                        html: [
                            active:true,
                            allowEmptyResults:true,
                            archive:true,
                            name: 'NYC/Mocha',
                            path: '**/coverage/html'
                        ],
                        lcov: [
                            active:true,
                            allowEmptyResults:true,
                            archive:true,
                            name: 'LCOV Coverage',
                            path: '**/coverage/lcov/lcov-report'
                        ]
                    )
                    cobertura coberturaReportFile: 'coverage/cobertura/cobertura-coverage.xml'
                    junit 'reports/mocha.xml'
                    cleanWs()
                  //  deleteDir()
                    script {
                        FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is when I execute the job on Jenkins I receive an error message:

```
find . -wholename **/reports/mocha.xml -exec touch {} ;
touch: cannot touch './reports/mocha.xml': Permission denied
```

I suppose the issue raised by junit command. How could I solve this problem?

P/S: Jenkins server runs on Ubuntu. I tried to modify /etc/sudoers and add this line to make Jenkins executes command as root. It still could not solve my problem.

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: what is "publishTestResults(
                        script: this,"
it's not builtin step right?

Comment: it's part of the standard Piper library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From checking the code at: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/blob/5c13a0e2a20132336824c70b743c364bcb5341f4/vars/testsPublishResults.groovy#L136

Looks like you can avoid the issue by setting `updateResults` to `false`

If you absolutely have to update the timestamp on the result file, you'll have to open a terminal session, go to the project workspace (with jenkins user) and try to run `touch ./reports/mocha.xml` and then debug it from there.

Comment: I tried running the `touch ./reports/mocha.xml` manually and everything is fine. It's only the jenkins job that could not run the command.

Comment: It looks like env issue (maybe you're trying with a different user?).

can you try the suggestion above? (updateResults=false)

Comment: you're correct. i'm running it with a specific Jenkins user given very limited permission. the thing here is it's neither allowed to give Jenkins user more permission nor switched to another user for the job.

Comment: then just set updateResults=false 

let me know if that worked